# How to submit a new block to the relay?

Tags: go-ethereum

I guess this question might be a bit elementary, I have EL and CL installed and running on my computer(geth and Prysm), and am currently synchronizing data from chain, now I am having some confusion, for example, I send a transaction to my node, this transaction will be packed into a new block, next, as far as I know I can send this block to other relays through the API (/relay/v1/builder/ blocks) such as flashbots and blocknative etc.
My question is how do I get this packaged block and send it to the above interface?
I've checked the documentation on geth but I can't seem to find an answer to this problem, can someone please explain this to me, thank you very much!